# User selects file names and writes the file names to a text file [Python]

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a python program that will prompt the user to select files (.txt) and then write these file names to a text file.  I am thinking I am on the right track but this is not working for me and I do not know why.  It creates the file list `.txt` but does not place the filenames into the text document.

```
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog
root = Tkinter.Tk()
files = tkFileDialog.askopenfilenames(parent = root, title = "Select files...", multiple =1)
SPSSList = open('list.txt', 'w')
SPSSList.write(files)
SPSSList.close()
```

Sorry if I am missing something obvious and I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file.write` takes a string; `askopenfilenames` returns a tuple of filenames.

Use

```
for f in files:
    print >> SPSSList, f
```

if you want to write them each on a separate line. Alternately,

```
SPSSList.write('\n'.join(files))
```

is somewhat more flexible since you can choose to use a different separator (e.g. `','.join`).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I think I can get it to work from here.

Comment: Is there a way to strip the file directory portion of the file names that are returned (i.e., '/Users/kyle/Desktop/...')?